# Grunt and ES6 modules in node - incompatible without the use of .mjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gruntjs, es6-modules

So, I'm dabbling a bit with Typescript and Grunt at the moment to see if it's worth it for me. The thing is: Typescript does not compile to `*.mjs` files but only regular `*.js` files. Node does support ES6 Modules but only if you either mark them as '*.jsm' files or by setting `"type": "module"`. Setting this top-level field in `package.json` however has global scope for any `*.js` file in the same directory and any following ones.

This breaks the `Gruntfile.js` file as it seems since it uses CommonJS modules, see my very basic Gruntfile as example:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
   grunt.initConfig({
      ts: {
         default: {tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json"}
      }
   })
   grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-ts");
   grunt.registerTask("default", ["ts"]);
}
```

Without expecting much success I naively changed the export syntax from `module.exports =` to `export default` which expectedly did no work since it didn't make much sense.

## Questions

1. Is there any option to use Grunt with ES6 modules enabled in node?
2. Is there a proper way to tell TypeScript to compile to `*.mjs` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested approach with Babel running before Grunt makes Grunt a bit redundant. Since TypeScript does not yet support exporting ES6 modules to `*.mjs` files (and you have to use the `*.mjs` suffix in your import when node should still be running with its CommonJS system) and will probably never fully (see [Design Meeting Notes 11/22/2019](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35589)) I have to conclude that ES6 modules still have serious implications and issues. Changing the file extension is *not enough* since the extension-less imports fail with node. You'd need to go through every compiled file and change the import to specifically load `*.mjs` files.

However, the TypeScript Compiler *can* be set up in a way that it does understand ES6 module syntax and to compile to CommonJS (see [TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    // [...]
  },
}
```

This way the TypeScript code be written with ES6 module syntax and the output can be CommonJS compatible without braking other code. As a bonus you can skip the Babel approach and grunt can run TS compiler.

Answer (score 4):

If you set `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`, you need to rename `Gruntfile.js` to `Gruntfile.cjs`, and run it with `grunt --gruntfile Gruntfile.cjs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can using babel-node to compile first. Which will resolve ES6 export and import problem.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/node
npx babel-node server.js
```

Comment: Adding Babel just for the sake of resolving this feels quite cumbersome and I'm thinking of ditching Grunt alltogether if that's the only solution. The alternative would be to get TypeScript to compile to `*.mjs` files.

Comment: Not to be ungrateful. Thanks for the suggestion! It's just that Grunt should be the automation solution that runs Babel and putting Babel before Grunt in the chain makes Grunt pointless.

Comment: Both Webpack and Grunt must use babel to compile the code for ES6, Grunt just an task runner. TypeScript also using babel to compile to javascript.

Comment: Since TS is also transpiling (wether with Babel or something else I don't know) I can just tell the TS compiler to do it directly. That's my solution at this point. But you are right. My thoughts took a wrong turn. The Babel approach of course does work and Grunt could run it obviously as well.